# How to uppercase all the words in excel spreadsheet using NPOI C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I need to convert all the words conataing in a sheet to uppercase using NPOI in C#; I can't find method to do this.

- Before applying uppercase : Cell[1;1]=stackoverflow
- After applying uppercase  : Cell[1;1]=STACKOVERFLOW

Comment: The `.ToUpper()` function is typically used in C# to convert a string to its uppercase equivalent.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks for your response, i need if possible to upercase all the words directly without looping all sheet cells,

Comment: Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible without looping through cells using NPOI.
Probably it can be done using Interop to Excel since it is possible to select range in file and perform some actions on it (like in Excel), but NPOI doesn't offers such ability.

Howewer, you don't need to loop through **all** cells in sheet since there exists properties `FirstRowNum` and `LastRowNum` and they gives you range of rows actually containing data.

So your loop could look like (converting to uppercase all strings from the first worksheet of file):

```
var hssfwb;
using (var file = new FileStream(@"your_file.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    file.Close();
}

var sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
for (int i = sheet.FirstRowNum; i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
{
    var row = sheet.GetRow(i);
    if (row != null)
    {
        foreach (ICell cell in row.Cells.Where(c => c.CellType == CellType.String))
            cell.SetCellValue(cell.StringCellValue.ToUpper());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i think that your solution is the best one to do this.

Comment: @DStanley oh.... wait, what COM calls are you talking about? Solution mentioned in my answer is just about NPOI - it doesn't uses any COM interface like Office Interop - it just writes files in MS Office formats.

Comment: Sorry, Andy - I completely glossed over the NPOI usage.